# i want to analyze captured packets but code gives error

Tags: python

I'm working on an ip filter application for vpn's and ddos protected vpn's, but when i try to run the program, my analyzer function (which i found most of the code for online) calls a syntax error. I just need help with these errors. Im getting errors from the lines with the semicolon and & symbol. Here's some of the function code where the errors originate from.

```
def packetAnalyzer(packet):
    data = packet[0]
    ip_header = data[0:20]

    unpack_data = unpack('!BBHHHBBH4s4s', ip_header)

    version_ihl = unpack_data[0]
    version = version_ihl &gt;&gt; 4
    ihl = version_ihl &amp; 0xF
    iph_length = ihl * 4
    ttl = iph[5]
    protocol = iph[6]
    s_addr = socket.inet_ntoa(iph[8]);
    d_addr = socket.inet_ntoa(iph[9]);

    print 'Version : ' + str(version) + ' IP Header Length : ' + str(ihl) + ' TTL : ' + str(ttl) + ' Protocol : ' + str(protocol) + ' Source Address : ' + str(s_addr) + ' Destination Address : ' + str(d_addr)

    tcp_header = data[iph_length:iph_length+20]

    tcph = unpack('!HHLLBBHHH', tcp_header)

    source_port = tcph[0]
    dest_port = tcph[1]
    sequence = tcph[2]
    acknowledgement = tcph[3]
    doff_reserved = tcph[4]
    tcph_length = doff_reserved &gt;&gt; 4

    print 'Source Port : ' + str(source_port) + ' Dest Port : ' + str(dest_port) + ' Sequence Number : ' + str(sequence) + ' Acknowledgement : ' + str(acknowledgement) + ' TCP header length : ' + str(tcph_length)

    h_size = iph_length + tcph_length * 4
    data_size = len(data) - h_size

    data = data[h_size:]

    print 'Data : ' + data
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "GV-Ddos-filter.py", line 1, in <module>
    import filterFunctions
  File "/home/ghostvip3r/Dev/python/Projects/server-client/VPN/ServerSide/AutoFilter/filterFunctions.py", line 17
    version = version_ihl &gt;&gt; 4
```

Comment: `inconsistent use of tabs and spaces` means you use tabs and spaces to create indentations. For you they looks the same - like four spaces - but for Python it makes difference. In some text editor/IDE you should have in some menu "convert tabs to spaces" or "convert spaces to tabs". Or in settings you may have "convert tabs to spaces when you save file"

Comment: Ok ill check on that.

Comment: So i updated the error im getting, idk why its calling syntax error when semicolons and & symbols are allowed in python. So any more help would be greatly appreciated.